# How do I create an additional README %doc file in an RPM spec file?

Tags: linux, rpm, rpmbuild

When creating a spec file, what is the proper procedure for creating an additional text doc file to be installed by the RPM, when that text file is not part of the original source?

For example, if the current %doc line includes the following files that **are** in the source:

```
%doc FEATURES KNOWNBUGS LICENSE README RELEASE_NOTES
```

and I want the spec file to create a README_FOO that will be written in the same docs directory (which contains package-specific configuration instructions), what's the proper way to do it?

I know I can create a text file in the %install section of the spec file with:

```
echo 'README_FOO contents go here
' > "$RPM_BUILD_ROOT"/README_FOO
```

but I'm not sure of the correct path to use after $RPM_BUILD_ROOT, or how to reference the new file in the existing %doc line or a new one.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest thing to do is to create a new %SOURCEx file and then copy it in during %prep. From there you can refer to it as normal in %doc.

Comment: Sorry - can you be a bit more specific with "copy it in"? I've created an additional source called readme.tar.gz (with three READMEs) and included it as Source2. Then in prep, I assume I untar it, but TO where? And then FROM where do I copy the untarred files? Thx.

Comment: Since it's a tarball you can just add it to `%setup` via `-a 2`. This will extract it into the same place as all the other files. Then from there you put them in %doc as you would any other file from there.